# KFGQPC Uthmanic Script Hafs - Diacritical marks are not displayed properly

Tags: flutter, fonts, arabic, arabic-support

I'm using the KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS - Font because it is the best looking font out there for my app. The only problem is, some characters are not displayed properly.

For example have a look at this:

[image]

The text, that should be displayed, looks like this:

أُو۟لَـٰٓئِكَ عَلَىٰ هُدًى مِّن رَّبِّهِمْ ۖ وَأُو۟لَـٰٓئِكَ هُمُ ٱلْمُفْلِحُونَ

Notice that circle (sukun) above the first و۟

If you ask which text I use to display the arabic text, its the following (in unicode):

```
\u0623\u064f\u0648\u06df\u0644\u064e\u0670\u0653\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0639\u064e\u0644\u064e\u0649\u0670 \u0647\u064f\u062f\u064b\u06ed\u0649 \u0645\u0651\u0650\u0646 \u0631\u0651\u064e\u0628\u0651\u0650\u0647\u0650\u0645\u0652 \u06d6 \u0648\u064e\u0623\u064f\u0648\u06df\u0644\u064e\u0670\u0653\u0626\u0650\u0643\u064e \u0647\u064f\u0645\u064f \u0671\u0644\u0652\u0645\u064f\u0641\u0652\u0644\u0650\u062d\u064f\u0648\u0646\u064e
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How to resolve this? I have plain arabic text (not unicode) i.e. أُو۟لَـٰٓئِكَ عَلَىٰ هُدًى مِّن رَّبِّهِمْ ۖ وَأُو۟لَـٰٓئِكَ هُمُ ٱلْمُفْلِحُونَ

and I am importing ttf file for the fonts i.e. KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS.ttf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all instances of `\u{06DF} ◌۟`  with `\u{0652} ◌ْ`  The original text you are using uses the Arabic Upper Zero characher instead of the Arabic Sukun character. That's why this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Salam ,

I really had the same problem , but i used KFGQPC Uthmanic Taha Naskh on Excel , when i changed to KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS , the display is correct .

I did arabic as the first language of display !